# Objective-C +load function with dispatch_once

Tags: objective-c, load

```
+ (void)load
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        //do my job
    });
}
```

I just wonder if a class with +load function just call once before main, so why need write `dispatch_once` inside?

Answer (score 0):

> I just wonder if a class with +load function just call once before main,

A `+load` method is not called "once before main" though that might be the common case, it is called once *by the runtime* after the image it is part of is loaded and with dynamically loaded images (see [Initializing Objective-C Classes](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/DynamicLibraries/100-Articles/DynamicLibraryDesignGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002013-SW34) in Apple's *Dynamic Library Programming Topics*) that might be after `main` – see the [`+load` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1418815-load?language=objc).

> so why need write dispatch_once inside?

If your code never directly calls `+load` then there seems to be no *need*, though there is no explicit discussion of thread safety in the *Dynamic Library Programming Topics* or in `+load`'s documentation as with the `+initialize` method.

However `+load` is just a method and can be called directly though it would unusual to do so, so maybe the writer just used `dispatch_once` out of an abundance of caution but we can't really know.

(Note: `+initialize` method can be called more than once by the runtime due to inheritance. However as `+initialize` is thread-safe a simple test can be used to ensure code is only run once, there is no need to use `dispatch_once`.)

HTH

Comment: Your explain of dispatch_once in load method is very useful.
But I get different opinion about load method call after main or before main.
I read some doc and source code(https://github.com/RetVal/objc-runtime).

When an App launch before main,it is divided into 4 parts:
1.dylib loading time;
2.rebase/binding time;
3.ObjC setup time;
4.initializer time;//call non-lazy class's load method.
------
As I marked load method call in initializer time.

Comment: @pogong - I maybe wasn't clear, a dynamic library can be loaded at any time during program execution and not just at program startup. Loading libraries later is an explicit action (e.g. see the mention of `dlopen()` in the linked docs) and indeed the name of the library to load may be determined dynamically during program execution. Any `+load` methods in such libraries must clearly be invoked after `main`.

Comment: OK,[a dynamic library can be loaded at any time during program execution].I must admit I get  a poor understanding of dynamic library.Thank you so much.

Comment: I think writing dispatch_once() inside a +load is an overabundance of caution. Even though it won't incur any perceptible performance penalty, it adds unnecessary complication and likely reflects a lack of understanding about the +load method.